# In/into/at What to use

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

So, English isn't my native language and my school teacher gave us this:

1. Complete: Let's go.............. my office.
   A) at 
   B) in
   C) out
   D) for
   E) into

I would go for at/in/into. She said it was "for" and explained it to me using some direct translations to my language, but that answer does not make any sense to me. Is "for" even a possible answer to this?

Comment: _In_ or _into_ are OK. _Go for X_ means 'make X the goal', but it's not used for describing normal motion, but rather group movements like coordinated attacks. _Go at X_ means 'work at or attack X strongly', probably not what the teacher had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a native British English speaker I would suggest your teacher has made a mistake: the only answer that makes any sense would be "into". Let's go through the alternatives.

A) at. To go "at" something means to attack or do it vigorously

> If I really go at my homework I can have it all done by dinner time.

B) in. To go "in" a place usually means, well, to at the very least urinate there.

> I was caught short on the way home and had to go in the bushes by the river.

C) out. You *can* go out *of* a place but the phrase "Let's go out my office" is terribly ungrammatical and wouldn't ever be the right answer to an exam question. As a side note, you can go out with someone - it means you're dating them.

D) for. To go for something can mean either going to obtain something or to attack something/someone.

> I'm hungry - let's go for a meal.
>
> That dog is a complete menace - it went for me again yesterday.

E) into. Correct - you are talking about you and your boss both moving into her office.

> Let's go into my office.

Absolutely standard usage.

Comment: In my opinion you _can_ 'go in' a room without any lavatorial implications, but 'into' is better.